# An abelian group whose endomorphism group $Hom(G,G)\cong \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $C$ be the category of all abelian groups and $G\in ob(C)$. When the morphism class $Hom(G,G)$ is an infinite cyclic group, I am trying to prove $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  If this is true, every additive and fully faithful functor $F: C\rightarrow C$ maps an infinite cyclic group to an infinite cyclic group.

If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, then $G$ is a finite diret sum of cyclic groups. Thus $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

But I don't know if this is right when $G$ is infinitely generated abelian group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's about $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)\cong G$ but asking for $\operatorname{End}(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is quite a different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there is a much more straightforward counterexample, but denote by $\mathcal{P}$ the set of prime numbers, and for each prime $p$ define $H_{p}=\left\{\frac{n}{\prod_{\substack{p'\in\mathcal{P}\\p'\leqslant p}}p'}\in\mathbb{Q}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. It is a subgroup of the (additive) abelian group $\mathbb{Q}$, consisting of all fractions whose denominator is a product of primes smaller than $p$ (appearing just once). For instance, $H_{5}$ consists of all rationals of the form $\frac{n}{30}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Put:
\begin{equation*}
G=\bigcup_{p\in\mathcal{P}}H_{p}\text{.}
\end{equation*}

It is also an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. Take $\varphi\in\operatorname{Hom}\left(G,G\right)$. Then $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi\left(1\right)$. Suppose that $\varphi\left(1\right)\notin\mathbb{Z}$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $\varphi\left(1\right)\in H_{p}$. Then $\varphi\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$ is of the form $\frac{n}{m}$, with $p^{2}\mid m$ and $n$ prime with $p$. Such numbers are not, by definition, in $G$, so we get a contradiction. Therefore, $\operatorname{Hom}\left(G,G\right)\cong\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Why is $G\not\cong\Bbb Z$? Put differently: Why is $\phi$ determined by $\phi(1)$? Because if homomorphism out of $G$ are determined by the image of a single element, $G$ satisfies the universal property of $\Bbb Z$, so $G \cong \Bbb Z$…

Comment: A simpler description of $G$ is that it is the group of rational numbers with squarefree denominator.

Comment: @PrudiiArca $G\not\cong\mathbb{Z}$ because every element of $G$ is divisible by infinitely many primes, but every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is only divisible by finitely many primes.

Comment: Thank you very much @JeremyRickard it is indeed much better formulated like this! And then one can just take $p$ to be a prime in the denominator of $\varphi\left(1\right)$ to get the same contradiction. I will leave my answer as it is, but it is clearly not the simplest way to write it.

Comment: @PrudiiArca What you are referring to is not the universal property of $\mathbb{Z}$. Its universal property is rather that for every abelian group $A$, then any $\varphi\in\operatorname{Hom}\left(\mathbb{Z},A\right)$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi\left(1\right)$, and it can be any element of $A$. Here, I have only done it with $A=G$, and moreover I have shown that it cannot take any value of $G$. In our case, $\varphi$ is still determined like this because $G$ has no torsion.

Comment: @user242429 I see. I understood that your assertion was about general homomorphisms out of $G$ being determined by the image of 1, which would have been the universal property of $\Bbb Z$. I did not read it as *this particular morphism is determined by the image of 1*…

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks, this makes sense…